# JSP input validate amount - possibly with REGEX

Tags: regex, jsp

This is probably a simple question that has been solved many times. I am new to front end dev, so struggling with the validation part. I have a currency input that I used the following statement in JavaScript to only allow numbers. Can I just edit this or add a line to also only allow two decimals as you type?

```
$("input#amountToSave").on("blur keyup", function() {
        this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]+/,'');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
^\$?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|0(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$
```

Many currency expresssions allow leading zeros, thus $01.40 passes thru them. This expression kills them, except for 0 in the one's column. Works with or without commas and/or dollar sign. Decimals not mandatory, unless no zero in ones column and decimal point is placed. Allows $0.00 and .0 Keywords: money dollar currency

E.g.,

```
$1,234.50 | $0.70 | .7
```

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? I pasted the REGEX between the two '/' that I had in my piece of code. Now it isn't even stoping me from entering characters? this.value=this.value.replace(/^\$?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|0(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$/,'');

Answer (score 0):

Okay - I think I see the problem. I need a regex (it can be a simple one for the two decimals - for now I don't need it too complex and no Currency symbol is necessary) that is inverted. I now saw when reading up I am testing if the value is not 0-9 replace with space. So I need to add to that reg exp that if it is the 3rd decimal, then replace with space.